open ssh cannot be accessed after update kernel ubuntu 24.04
Can anyone help? I just installed the ubuntu server ubuntu 24.04 LTS for the webserver, and everything works fine, after updating the kernel sftp cannot be accessed, I have tried updating ssh_config but it is still not working.

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 22.04 SSH the RSA key isn't working since upgrading from 20.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you for answering so quickly, I'll try it first,
